# Why does the 'window.resize' event fire when changing tabs in Chrome (6.0.472.55)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I came across an interesting <strike>bug</strike> feature tonight when writing a handler for `window.onresize` in Chrome (the latest version 6.0.472.55). First open two tabs, then in the first tab open [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urKRJ/).

Resize the window at will and the dialog box works as expected. Now, try switching to the 2nd tab -_-. Why is `resize` firing when the tab is changed? Could someone provide insight/more details if I need to file a bug?

Comment: Very interesting find- confirmed Google Chrome 6.0.472.55

Comment: I think it's a bug: it doesn't fire on tab change in Chrome 6.0.472.55 on Linux (Ubuntu 10.4)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. Chrome 7.0.517.5 dev on Mac OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bug has been filed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55793) with Google. For the time being, I've just ignored it since my actual `onresize` handler doesn't display alert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Well how about that? Sounds like a bug. I would guess that `onresize` is listened-for by a combination of behaviors, probably new data about the page size that, for whatever reason, is coming in when a tab is focused.

In the version I use on Windows, 5.0.375.127, it doesn't happen, but if I actually resize the window, the resize event fires *twice*.

Knowing it's there, you can take a step to defeat it (that Google ought to do for you eventually). Wrap an `if` statement around your handler that checks for an actual change in the `clientHeight` or `clientWidth` if you need something to happen only if the event (as we understand it) *actually* occurs.

Answer (score 1):

From the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55793):

> When using Dev Tools in splitview and switching to a Tab without Dev
>   Tools opened in split, the resize-Event will be fired.
>
> So, if the next Tab doesn't have the same window size, resize() will
>   be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Without a working knowledge of how Chrome handles tab switching and page rendering, my guess is as good (or bad, depending how you look at it) as the next guy's. I would guess that rerendering the page, or reloading the already rendered page if it caches it, triggers the `onresize` event. This is what happens when the tab is switched. Following my theory, I would guess that Chrome doesn't trigger the resize event on initial page view because it has been designed not to. But again, as I don't know how Chrome handles tab switching internally, this is just speculation (food for thought).