# Developer tools and switching between tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When developing I have the developer tools open on one or more of my tabs. If I then switch to one which has not had it open then a resize event is fired. The actual size of that page has not changed but the resize event occurs which pushes thing around my page. I came across a similar post regarding an bug which has since been fixed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713838/why-does-the-window-resize-event-fire-when-changing-tabs-in-chrome-6-0-472-55)

Using his same js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urKRJ/. You can test it by opening one tab with the developer tools open and switching to the fiddle. I am using canary build. Is this a bug or should it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128941 has been posted and is been allocated